# PowerShell - JSON Format Query - "Invalid JSON payload received"

Tags: json, powershell, api, logging, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently struggling to make use of the Google Cloud Logging API with PowerShell, but I'm running into issues with the JSON format.

The links I'm presently using are:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.metrics/create

Essentially, I'm trying to create a new custom logging metric within a Google Cloud project. I know there's something wrong with the JSON format, but I honestly don't know what, so perhaps someone here could advise. My code is as follows:

```
Begin{
    $Cred = gcloud auth print-access-token
    $Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $Cred" }
    $URI = "https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/projectname/metrics"
    $Body1 = @{
        Name = "snapshot-api-createcluster-fail"
        Description = "The API call of createCluster fails whilst taking a snapshot."
        Filter = '"resource.type="gce_disk" severity>=ERROR protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.disks.createSnapshot""'
    }
    $CreateHostJSON = ConvertTo-Json($Body1)
}
Process{
    Try{
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method POST -Body $CreateHostJSON -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json"
        }
    Catch{
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
        $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $streamReader.Close()
        Break
    }
}
```

When checking $ErrResp.error.message, I see the following output:

*Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Filter" at 'metric': Cannot find field.*

*Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Description" at 'metric': Cannot find field.*

*Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Name" at 'metric': Cannot find field.*

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making `$Body1` hashtable keys lowercase:

```
$Body1 = @{
    name = "snapshot-api-createcluster-fail"
    description = "The API call of createCluster fails whilst taking a snapshot."
    filter = '"resource.type="gce_disk" severity>=ERROR protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.disks.createSnapshot""'
}
```

Comment: *sigh* That's really annoyingly obvious now that you've pointed it out. Thanks very much!